# Help understanding expansion for following $\sin(\theta)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, approximations

my professor posted a solution to a problem that I am having trouble understanding.

This is the question:
Find the frequency of small oscillations about the stable equilibrium position.

And this is the solution:
"We consider a small displacement from equilibrium, $\theta=\theta_0+\delta$ and substitute it into the equation of motion.  We then expand the equation in $\delta$ and its derivatives, keeping only up to linear terms:

$\sin(\theta_0+\delta)=\sin(\theta_0)\cos(\delta)+\cos(\theta_0)\sin(\delta)=\sin\theta_0(1+O(\delta^2))+\cos\theta_0(\delta+O(\delta^3))$
$\cos(\theta_0+\delta)=\cos(\theta_0)\cos(\delta)-\sin(\theta_0)\sin(\delta)=\cos\theta_0(1+O(\delta^2))-\sin\theta_0(\delta+O(\delta^3))$

I see that the expression in the middle is a trig identity, but I don't understand the RHS.  Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Hint: What is $\sin(\delta)$ approximately equal to when $\delta$ is very close to zero? What is $\cos(\delta)$ approximately equal to when $\delta$ is very close to zero?

Comment: The RHS is incorrect. Also in the LHS I assume you mean $\theta$ instead of $\theta_0$. If $\delta$ is small $\sin \delta \simeq \delta$ and $\cos \delta \simeq 1$ in lowest order.

Comment: @Praan:  Yes, it is definitely incorrect.  I will make the changes, thank you for commenting

Comment: @march, thanks for the hint, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $\delta$ you can approximate $sin(\delta)\approx 0$ and $cos(\delta)\approx 1$:
The Taylor expansion of $sin(\delta)$ around zero is:

sin$(\delta)=\delta - \delta^3 / 3!+\delta^5 / 5!$ + higher orders.

Hence $\delta\approx0$ results in sin$(\delta)\approx 0$.

However the Taylor expansion for cos$\delta$ is:

cos$(\delta)=1 - \delta^2 / 2+\delta^4 / 4!$ + higher orders.

So for $\delta\approx0$ we have cos$(\delta)\approx 1$.

Your professor's answer means that only first and second terms of Taylor expansion of cos$\delta$ are kept and the rest are ignored due to their small amount.